# use azure cli command to change the reference image of vmss and update the vm running under the vmss

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to use azure cli command to change the reference image of vmss and update the vm running under the vmss.

I used to use UI to update the reference image as shown below.

[image]

I tried following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/vmss?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vmss_update

but not getting exact command, am I going in wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment to change the reference images of VMSS but it seems not possible using below `cmd`.

```
Update-AzVmss ` -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" ` -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" ` -ImageReferenceId /subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myNewImage
```

[image]

If you want to [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#update-the-os-image-for-your-scale-set) the **version of reference image** you can change with the below command.

```
Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" -ImageReferenceVersion 16.04.201801090
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the CLI command I have used

```
az vmss update --name MyScaleSet --resource-group MyResourceGroup --set virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id=imageID
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?